# Add new object in Relation and render JSON together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a SQL search and it returns a Relation From Active Record.
I need to iterate in this return and add a new object from its Relationship with other table and finally render json of it all together.

Example: I have this return

```
example = #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Documento::Andamento id: 00001, nr_documento: 20211>, #<Documento::Andamento id: 00002, nr_documento: 20212>, #<Documento::Andamento id: 00003, nr_documento: 20213>, #<Documento::Andamento id: 00004, nr_documento: 21214>]>

lista = Array.new
  example.each do |andamento|
    movimento = andamento
    movimento.objeto_tramitacao_interesse = andamento.objeto_tramitacao.objeto_tramitacao_interesse //relatioship
    lista << movimento
    end

  render json: {autos_andamentos:[lista]}
```

I've tried something like this but went wrong

I want to iterare and add a new object from a relationship table and render json of it all together

Answer (score 1):

If this is only needed to generate some output and *not* change the actual records, then you could convert the object to JSON before getting the nested object. This would allow you to manually add nested resources using the existing relationship and append the whole hash to the `lista` array to build your payload like this:

```rb
example = #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Documento::Andamento id: 00001, nr_documento: 20211>, #<Documento::Andamento id: 00002, nr_documento: 20212>, #<Documento::Andamento id: 00003, nr_documento: 20213>, #<Documento::Andamento id: 00004, nr_documento: 21214>]>
lista = Array.new

example.each do |andamento|
  movimento = andamento.as_json
  movimento["objeto_tramitacao_interesse"] = andamento.objeto_tramitacao.objeto_tramitacao_interesse

  lista << movimento
end

render json: { autos_andamentos: [lista] }
```

*Note: using `as_json` will return a hash with string keys which is what we need here, as opposed to `to_json` which would return an escaped JSON string.*

Comment: movimento["objeto_tramitacao_interesse"] = andamento.objeto_tramitacao.objeto_tramitacao_interesse returns nill

Comment: That will be because the value of `andamento.objeto_tramitacao.objeto_tramitacao_interesse` is `nil`. I'm just reusing your code example, I don't know anything about your application and the data stored in its objects.